# Hide div when sub-components "empty" (nothing to display)

Tags: jquery, dom, html, traversal

Fairly novice when it comes to jQuery, so thanks in advance for bearing with me :)

For divs with set widths and heights, I'm looking for a way to hide (set display: none;) these containers when nothing is displayed on the browser.  Moreoften then not, when they have nested HTML which complicates things a bit, as sub-components need to be checked for emptiness/display:none;.

The closest I've come so far is by using the .text() method, trimming it for whitespace, and checking the length.  However, .text() ignores styles and also grabs hidden text and since it doesn't return the DOM structure is difficult to filter over.

Here's the fiddle I've been playing with: http://jsfiddle.net/JbBkQ/5/
I'd like for the div with "Hidden Content" in it to be caught by the first jQuery function, since the

Hidden Content is surrounded in has it's display set to none.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Would .is(":visible") help? This would return a boolean.

Comment: @hackNightly I was just thinking the same thing but an empty div with fixed size is still :visible.

Comment: Ahhh, yes you're right. I misunderstood the question

Comment: @hackNightly: were you thinking after the .text()?  I looked into that hoping I could use the :visible selector but since .text() doesn't return a DOM, I don't think there's anything for it to filter over.  Applying the :visible selector to the container div itself also doesn't seem to work, as that's the thing who's visibility I'd like to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selects the div's your looking for
iterate over them and filter the child collection based on being visible or not. If no children are visible hide the element it self.

```
$("div").each(function(){
   if(!this.children().find(":visible").length){
       this.hide();
   }
}
```

not this will not work correctly if the divs you are selecting can be nested inside each other (a div with another div that is being hidden might not be hidden it self, depending on the order of selection)

**EDIT**

if you only wanted to go down one level you could use filter instead of find

```
$("div").each(function(){
     if(!this.children().filter(":visible").length){
         this.hide();
     }
}
```

Comment: Nice. To expand upon this, 

`if(($(this).children().length) && (!$(this).children().find(":visible").length)) {
   (this).parent().html('<p class="e">Fire 1st</p>');
}`

Question: this only goes a level deep right?  Is there anyway to recuse down the DOM structure?

Comment: @Dizzy you don't need to test children length and find goes all the way down. filter on the other hand only goes one level down the tree

Answer (score 0):

If understand you right you can try yo use [`:empty` pseudo class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo)

### [online demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/2875872)

```
div:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: If I understand OP correctly the elements to be hidden might contain elements that are either hidden them self or empty. The :empty selector will not work for those